# fill DataTable with asp grid view data

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable

I've a grid view having text box.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="AgriGrid"
runat="server"
AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S. No.">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblagrigridsn" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("sn") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CROPS">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblcropsagrigrid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("crops") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PRODUCTION">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <input type="number" min="0" value="0" id="txtAgriGridProduction" class="form-control" onkeypress="return numberOnly(event)" runat="server" autocomplete="off">
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CULTIVATED LAND">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAgriGridCultivatedLand" Width="80px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CULTIVATED LAND UNIT">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAgriGridCultivatedUnit" Width="80px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SALES">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <input type="number" min="0" value="0" class="form-control" onkeypress="return numberOnly(event)" runat="server" id="txtAgriGridSell" autocomplete="off">
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The user fills the production quantity in the grid textbox `txtAgriGridProduction`. On submit button press I am trying to insert the asp grid data to a DataTable. But I am getting null values.

submit button code block

```
 DataTable agricrops_dt = new DataTable();
agricrops_dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CROPS", typeof(string)));
agricrops_dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PRODUCTION", typeof(int)));
DataRow drow = null;
foreach (GridViewRow gr in AgriGrid.Rows)
{
    drow = agricrops_dt.NewRow();
    drow["CROPS"] = gr.Cells[1].Text;
    drow["PRODUCTION"] = gr.Cells[2].Text;
    agricrops_dt.Rows.Add(drow);
}
```

But I am getting null values. Why is it so?

Comment: Try using `Label lblCrops = gr.FindControl("lblcropsagrigrid") as Label` followed with `drow["CROPS"] = lblCrops.Text`. Is the value still null in `DataRow`?

Comment: Why are you trying to get the values of the GridView into a DataTable? Why not use the data that is bound to the GridView?

Comment: @VDWWD what I am trying to do is pass the grid view data to database. The grid view contains text boxes that are filled by the users. After the user fills the data and presses the submit button I've to insert data to database. How can I do that? Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By inspecting your code we can say that change `asp:TextBox` to `input type="text"` then make

```
drow["CULTIVATED_LAND"] = ((HtmlInputControl)gr.FindControl("txtAgriGridCultivatedLand")).Value;
drow["CULTIVATED_LAND_UNIT"] = ((HtmlInputControl)gr.FindControl("txtAgriGridCultivatedUnit")).Value;
```

But if you want to use `asp:TextBox` then you have to use

```
  drow["CULTIVATED_LAND"] =  ((TextBox)gr.FindControl("txtAgriGridCultivatedLand")).Text;
  drow["CULTIVATED_LAND_UNIT"] =  ((TextBox)gr.FindControl("txtAgriGridCultivatedUnit")).Text;
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

HTML Markup

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S.No.">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblagrigridsn" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("sn") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CROPS">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblcropsagrigrid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("crop") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PRODUCTION">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <input type="text" min="0" value="0" class="form-control" onkeypress="return numberOnly(event)" runat="server" id="txtAgriGridProduction" autocomplete="off" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Crop]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click1" Text="Button" />
```

Code Behind Method on Button Click

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable agricrops_dt = new DataTable();
    agricrops_dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CROPS", typeof(string)));
    agricrops_dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PRODUCTION", typeof(int)));
    DataRow drow = null;
    foreach (GridViewRow gr in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        drow = agricrops_dt.NewRow();
        drow["CROPS"] = ((Label)gr.FindControl("lblcropsagrigrid")).Text;
        drow["PRODUCTION"] = ((HtmlInputControl)gr.FindControl("txtAgriGridProduction")).Value;
        agricrops_dt.Rows.Add(drow);
    }


}
```

You have your Data in the Data Table.

Comment: I've to fill `DataTable` with `grid view` data, why should I use textbox then?

Comment: becuase your Data in inside the TextBox which sits inside Template Field.. Am i missing a plot here???

Comment: Yes my data is in the `text box` of grid. I've to copy the grid data to `DataTable`. Your code is not showing how can I copy all the data of the grid to the `DataTable`. Will you please provide the complete solution? Thank You!

Comment: Ok I will provide

Comment: I am getting error `Message = "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputControl'."` in the line `drow["PRODUCTION"] = ((HtmlInputControl)gr.FindControl("txtAgriGridProduction")).Value;`. Please help.

Comment: Change the type to TextBox then...drow["PRODUCTION"] = ((TextBox)gr.FindControl("txtAgriGridProduction")).Text;

Comment: Now getting error as `{"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputGenericControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'."}`. Please help.

Comment: First tell us whether you have asp:textbox or an html input  in your item template. You need to cast the control to whatever you have in your markup. That's it

Comment: I've update my code, please check. I've two `asp:Label` , two `input type="number"` and two `asp:TextBox`